# Scala/Java POST request works first time, then NULL ptr exception error

Tags: scala, servlets, pdfbox, json4s

I run the request in my servlet and it works well the first time I run it.  The following instances don't work though.  I get a 500 error (Nullptr exception).

I have to restart the server for it to work again.

Here is my post request code, very simple:

```
def getResp(resp: HttpServletResponse, msg: String )
 {
    val out: PrintWriter = resp.getWriter()
    out.println(msg)
  }

    override def doPost(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse) = {

      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE")
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600")
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, content-type")

      getResp(response, createFile(request.getReader.readLine()))
    }
```

And here is the code that creates the file from the data given in the post request:

```
val document = new PDDocument()
sealed trait Value

  case class value1(subval: String) extends Value

  case class value2(`trait`: Int) extends Value


  implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) +
    new newSerializer

  object newSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Value](format => ({
    case JString(newT) => value1(newT)
    case JInt(newZ) => value2(newZ.toInt)
  }, {
    case value1(v1) => JString(v1)
    case value2(v2) => JInt(v2)
  }))

def createFile(json: String): String = {

    val myJSON = parse(json).extract[Value]

      val blankPage: PDPage = new PDPage()
      val contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, blankPage)

////DO SOMETHING....THEN:
str = "/path/"
try {
      document.save(str)
    }
    finally {
      document.close()
    }
str
```

Here is the output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream.<init>(PDStream.java:71)
    org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream.<init>(PDPageContentStream.java:258)
    org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream.<init>(PDPageContentStream.java:173)
    org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream.<init>(PDPageContentStream.java:158)
    com.pdf.FileServlet.createFile(FileServlet.scala:142)
    com.pdf.FileServlet.doPost(FileServlet.scala:78)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

If you have any suggestions or advice, that'd be very helpful.  I don't know how to proceed with little idea of where the problem might be.  It works at first, but not on subsequent occasions, which is strange to me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You haven't added the most important information: the log of the error.

Comment: Line 142 in createFile references "contentStream" initialization

Comment: You also haven't added the part of code where your `document` variable is initialized or declared.

Comment: I added this.  It occurs immediately after the servlet is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you create the `document` object only once, but you write to it and `close` it on each request. Usually, objects that have a `close` method cannot be reused after the `close` method has been invoked.

Just move your `val document = new PDDocument()` declaration where you declared the `blankPage`, so that a new document is created for each request.

Comment: @nietsnegttiw You're welcome. I'm glad I could help :)